# Start explorer.exe remotely with a path specified in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, dcom

The problem I have is that I am able to Invoke-command explorer.exe on a remote machine without giving it any path parameters, yet when I enter:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName PC01 -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock  {explorer.exe "C:\Foldername"}
```

Nothing happens, except for the fact that I get an error entry in the logs saying:

The server {75DFF2B7-6936-4C06-A8BB-676A7B00B24B} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: And what identity are you trying to run this process under ultimately? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, If you are trying this directly on the local system, the GUI will pop up properly.

```
Invoke-Command  -ScriptBlock  {C:\Windows\explorer.exe "C:\folder"}
```

But the problem, is how powershell will open a GUI console invoked from the remote system. Basically, it does not have the session to hold. *You need a **desktop session** to do that*.

In that case, you should use **PSEXEC** with **-i**

```
psexec -i -d -s c:\windows\explorer.exe C:\folder
```

Download it from Here: [PSExec-v2.11](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec). This link has all the explanations with examples on how to use each utility.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, who (which user account) will see this on the target computer?

Comment: In target system, someone has to be logged in. Desktop session should be present.

Comment: @RanadipDutta; Thank you for the answer. However, the problem I have encountered is the fact, that I can only execute the command in this manner when it is typed in manually. If I try to put it into a saved script - it tries to execute everything locally. The aim of my code is to surpass all the password prompts, create a folder on remote PC and open it interactively.

Comment: @RanadipDutta; This works just fine when entered manually into the console: 

`$username = "PC01\User";
$password = "Password01";
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString;
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)};
$cred = new-object -typename; System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr;
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName PC01 -Credential $cred;
$path = "PC01\C:\testfolder";
New-Item -Path $path -ItemType directory;
psexec.exe -i -s C:\windows\explorer.exe "C:\testfolder";
Exit-PSSession;`